# Are there arbitratily long runs of consecutive integers n that are NOT of the form $n = p^k$ or $n = 2p^k$ for some $k>0$ and $p$ an odd prime?

Tags: probability, number-theory

I know that there are arbitrarily long runs of consecutive non-primes.  I am interested in this question because an  integer  $n>4$ has a primitive root if and only if it has the form $n = p^k$ or $n = 2p^k$.

I am ultimately trying to determine the answer to this question: Select a random integer $m \in {1,2,...,n}$.  Then randomly select an integer $r$ from the set of positive integers relatively prime to $m$.  Let $P(n)$ be the probability that $r$ is a primitive root of $m$.  What is the (or does there exist a) limit of $P(n)$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: If we take $15$ consecutive numbers, one of them is for sure a multiple of $15$, hence neither a prime power or twice a prime power.

Comment: @Geoffrey I think you should ask a new question, even if it was just a mistake (forgetting the 'not' I mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\pi(x)\sim x/\log x$ primes up to $x$ and $\pi(x/2)\sim x/2\log x$ even semiprimes up to $x$. The highest power up to $x$ is $\lfloor\log_2x\rfloor$ and so there are $\ll2\log_2x\sqrt x$ other numbers of the form $p^k$ or $2p^k$ up to $x$. As a result $P(n)\sim\frac{3}{2\log n}\to0$ and hence there are arbitrarily long runs of numbers without primitive roots.

Comment: OK Thanks.  I see now that your assymptotic is verified by Vaclav Kotesovec in Sloane's OEIS A252649.  I do not understand the argument leading to 3/(2*log(n)) but that is my problem.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer: All that matters for the asymptotic are primes (n/log n) and twice primes (0.5n/log n) which sum to 1.5n/log n and average 1.5/log n = 3/(2 log n). Squares, cubes, etc. are too rare to care about (as shown in my answer).

Comment: OK! Thanks. Now I at least see where the 1.5 comes from.  Except (of course)  I really don't know why Pi(x) ~ x/logx.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer: That's the Prime Number Theorem and it was the crowning achievement of 19th century analytic number theory.

Answer (score 0):

Multiples of $15$ provide an easily understood limit.

Also, if we take $8$ consecutive integers, two of them are multiples of $4$ and assuming the numbers concerned are greater than $4$, at most one of those is a prime power.

Comment: I am very sorry.  I meant NOT of the form p^k or 2*p^k

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer - No worries. You might be interested in [my question about primitive roots](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186548/count-of-lower-and-upper-primitive-roots-of-prime-p-equiv-3-bmod-4)